# Telerik MVC controls still loading jQuery Validation even after setting it not to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a project I'm working on and I'm using the Telerik MVC controls.  I have the newest open source version.

In my _Layout.cshtml, I have the following line:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
    group.Combined(false)
         .Compress(false))
    .jQuery(false)
    .jQueryValidation(false))
```

I want to load jQuery and jQueryValidation myself by using Cassette.  The above line keeps jQuery from loading in favor of the location and version I've specified.

My problem is that when I bring up a page with a grid on it, the jquery.validation.min.js that exists in the telerik script directory still gets loaded as well as the one I have specified from a different directory.

Why is the ScriptRegistrar still loading jQueryValidation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug which caused this erroneous behavior. Try downloading the latest internal build.

Comment: I'm using the Open Source Version, so I don't suppose I can get the latest internal build, can I?

Comment: Nope. But you can always fix the problem in the source. Check ScriptRegistrar.cs

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to replace the jquery.validation.min.js that exists in the telerik script directory with an empty file.